# Gravitational waves from collapsing rotating mass?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, kerr-metric, gravitational-collapse

According to the Birkhoff’s theorem, a non-rotating mass does not radiate gravitational waves during a spherically symmetric collapse. There is, however, no equivalent of the Birkhoff’s theorem for a rotating mass. For this reason the spacetime outside a real rotating body is not described by the Kerr metric. While there is no exact solution, I wonder if it is possible to state conceptually if a rotating (but initially spherically symmetric) body would produce gravitational waves during a gravitational collapse.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104539/discussion-on-question-by-safesphere-gravitational-waves-from-collapsing-rotatin).

Comment: @tpg2114 Per suggestions of Qmechanic and A.V.S., I have edited the question to remove the reason it was closed. Please reopen. Thank you!

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean when you specify that the body is initially spherically symmetric. Are you requiring the energy-momentum tensor to be spherically symmetric? If so, that requirement is incompatible with the body rotating.

Comment: @mmeent It is a rotating ball (e.g. not a rotating cube) before the collapse starts.

Comment: @safesphere if you made it axially symmetric that would remove all ambiguity. But in any case you need a time dependent quadrupole to get gravitational waves and a spherically or axially symmetric rotating body has no quadrupole, time dependent or otherwise.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks John, but the axial symmetry does not guarantee the absence of radiation, such as in a head-on collision of two bodies. What you are referring to is a stationary case, not a dynamic collapse. My question is if the collapse would not radiate provided the shape of the object doesn’t change. For example, it is a shrinking ball. In the linked chat A.V.S. claims this shape is not uniquely defined, but I don’t see it. The coordinate system itself is affine (short of the origin) unaffected by the metric, so the Schwarzschild timeslices should be uniquely defined.